# Label following circle shape jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, while-loop

I want the label of percentage to follow the circular pattern like so (orange):
[image]

See demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dsfpb (change `data-attribute` of html element to see changes)

Currently I’m controlling the position of label with the `width` of the element that crops the blue circle. I have this code:

```
if (percentage >= 0 && percentage <= 25)
  $(this).css('width', 65 + '%');
if (percentage > 25 && percentage <= 50)
  $(this).css('width', 100 + '%');
if (percentage > 50 && percentage <= 75)
  $(this).css('width', 100 + '%');
if (percentage > 75 && percentage <= 95)
  $(this).css('width', 65 + '%');
if (percentage > 95 && percentage <= 100)
  $(this).css('width', 45 + '%');
```

Is there a way to improve this? Some percentages are not looking well (try '20%', '80%', '0%' for example). And maybe simplify it? I tried using a loop like so (not complete):

```
var j = 100;
while (i--) {
  if (percentage <= 50) {
    j = j - 2;
    if (j <= 0)
      j = 0;
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: rather than reinvent the wheel, have you considered using a plugin such as http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/ ?

Comment: Thanks, but how is your comment relevant to what I’m asking? That plugin allows a circle to be manipulated by touch and mouse click. Even for that plugin, I don’t see the label positioned on the outer ring moving along the “fill”. He has it inside the circle, static.

Comment: just thought it might be helpful. Might be possible to do exactly what you are looking for by looking at the css applied to the label and there is a callback function you can use aswell.

Comment: If you are not worried about space you can adjust .address-book-completion__chart__cropping:after and change right:-40px to -50px

Answer (score 0):

Position the numbers based on the distance from the center of the circle by horizontal and vertical. Of course, the actual hor/ver numbers will need to be converted to values relative to the element () it's contained from the circle's center. There will need to be some positional placement adjustments to the numbers relative to the actual circle because, for example, the right side of the circle, the numbers will be positioned relative to their left-hand corner. This would need to be corrected for numbers positioned on the left side of the circle otherwise, they would overlapped the circle.

A small flash movie would make the task much easier.

Instead of positioning the numbers, one could simply limit the numbers displayed to tens (0, 10, 20, 30...) and make the numbers into transparent png's(or gif) with the overall size of the png being the size of the element that contains the circle and use as a background image. This way, you need only call the image when needed and not worry about placement.